# How to use in built Auth model in django to manage login for 4000-5000 users belongs to different Company

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am new to Django and i am working on one requirement where i have multiple company for example A,B,C,D and each Company will have 1000 Users.
I have used Django inbuilt Auth Module for authentication purpose and created one model as shown below.

```
class ShiftChange(models.Model):
        ldap_id = models.CharField(max_length=64)
        Vendor_Company = models.CharField(max_length=64,choices=VENDOR_CHOICES,default='genesys')
        EmailID =  models.EmailField(max_length=64,unique=True)
        Shift_timing = models.CharField(max_length=64,choices=SHIFT_CHOICES,default='General_Shift')
        Reason = models.TextField(max_length=256)
        # updated_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Below are the things which i have created.
For login i'm using django inbuilt **User** model and i am using email id to filter result as shown below in my view so in this when user is login based on his email id data getting filter and he Can see only his data.

```
def retrieve_view(request):
    # alluser = ShiftChange.objects.all()
    alluser = ShiftChange.objects.filter(EmailID=request.user.email)
    # alluser = ShiftChange.objects.filter(ShiftChange.ldap_id == request.user.username)
    return render(request, 'apple/shift2.html', {'alluser': alluser})
```

**Task:** Instead of asking all 4000 user to login by Creating account i want if this can be possible by creating some group from django admin where i Can add all user belonging to one Company and create only one login access and share it with respective POC of Company A(Company A person should not see data of Company B,C,D).
2.other way of doing this i'm thinking to Create separate model for all 4 Company and add users belonging to that model(company) but again question is how to manage authorization by using django default Auth> User because when i am Creating login user Can see either data matching to his email ID OR all data

Any Suggestion on this will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use django-allauth to connect the already created users, if there is some provider available, for example gmail or Microsoft

https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html

Answer (score 0):

You could consider to do it like a multi tenant page using postgres. *See information here: [django multi tenant](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-multi-tenant/en/latest/)*

Then you could make one db for every company, where they got their own user table etc.